# How to set minimum height on material cards in Material UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a card which has a table nested inside it. The card expands as the table expands. However when the table has no data or a single entry, the card also shrinks. I want to set a minimum height to the card so that even if my table inside has just one entry or no entries , the card does not shrink. However it should expand when the table gets populated by more rows.

My code is as follows:

```
    const BaseCard = () =>
       <div id="card-containerBase">
       <Card
          style={{
          width: '100%',
          margin: 'auto',
          padding: '10px',
          backgroundColor: '#ECEFF1',
    }}
   >
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `min-height` on you card/table ?

Comment: Yeah this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Krusader points out, the minimum height can be set using min-height.
However inside material UI Card styling the property should be set as
minHeight.
I set the parameter as:

```
    minheight: '30vw'
```

Answer (score 3):

> just add the following style:

**`minHeight: '30vw'`**